# Can´t find angular/material/theming after upgrade angular/Material15

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular14, angular15

After installing angular15, my application works correctly. But when installing angular/material15, pages lose some of their styles. Buttons are displaced, the font of the letters changes, div is moved. I noticed that there is an import that goes to a file that it does not find: `@angular/material/theming`. Can this be related? How can I get this file? Was renamed? Any hint please?

I use the next commands with the same result:

```
    ng add @angular/material
    npm install @angular/material@latest
    ng update @angular/material --force
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if `@angular/material/theming` has a preceeding `~` then remove it.

As for the lost styles this is because in Material 15 many components were completely re-written and others got a style updates. A migration tool is provided that helps you with the migration. For that run

```
ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration
```

However, practically you'll probably still have to do a lot of manual changes depending on the complexity of your application. My advice when migrating is to migrate component by component and check your application each time for changes.

Use [this](https://rc.material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration) guide as a reference